# How to play video from YouTube URL like VLC?

Tags: qt, youtube, vlc, phonon

I'm using Qt with Phonon, I'd like the program I'm writing to be able to play a YouTube video from a URL, I've tried googling it but none of the methods I found work. If you put a YouTube URL on VLC, it will play it. Can anyone please tell me how they do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

download the video (qnetworkacess) and then play it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The thing is that you can't download a video from just its normal URL, that would download the HTML page. You need to get the direct URL to the video, then download that, do you know how to do it?

Comment: inside the html you can find the url of the video. Anyway you can use a http debugger, like Fiddler, to see it.

Answer (score -3):

You shouldn't do this. It's because YouTube owns that stream and by passing it into VLC, you're essentially stealing it. I know it's a lame answer, but if you want to play it on VLC, why not just play it using the YouTube player?

Comment: I disagree, why does chaning the method of access to a stream constitute stealing that stream? if the stream is unecrypted or uses a non-propietary method for encoding the stream (That other players can play) then your just using an alternative means to access a freely available resource.

Comment: It's still stealing the stream which you're not supposed to do.